# How to uniquely identify a work book in excel

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

We have an excel add in with user roles based functionalities. We have an idea of creating a sample workbook with all the feature access for demo purpose. Do we have any unique identifiers for workbooks in excel ? If exists how can we access them using officejs. We did a research in officejs documentation and found out that Worksheets inside a workbook has unique identifiers. The disadvantage is that these id will be reused when the worksheet is deleted and new worksheet is created.

[Reference link of worksheet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheets) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following Officejs API to save a UDID along with the workbook. This will be persisted with the workbook.

Office.context.document.settings.set("Worksheet_ID", 'your_unique_identifier''); Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();

Reference link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.settings?view=word-js-preview#saveasync-options--callback-

Comment: Thank you dinesh, this seems to do the job

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use the `office.document.url` property to use to identify the workbook URL.

In addition, you can also set/get a custom property on the worksheet level:

```js
Excel.run(function (context) {
    // Add the custom property.
    var customWorksheetProperties = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().customProperties;
    customWorksheetProperties.add("WorksheetGroup", "Alpha");

    return context.sync();
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);

[...]

Excel.run(function (context) {
    // Load the keys and values of all custom properties in the current worksheet.
    var worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    worksheet.load("name");

    var customWorksheetProperties = worksheet.customProperties;
    var customWorksheetProperty = customWorksheetProperties.getItem("WorksheetGroup");
    customWorksheetProperty.load(["key", "value"]);

    return context.sync().then(function() {
        // Log the WorksheetGroup custom property to the console.
        console.log(worksheet.name + ": " + customWorksheetProperty.key); // "WorksheetGroup"
        console.log("  Custom value : " + customWorksheetProperty.value); // "Alpha"
    });
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks#worksheet-level-custom-properties.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=excel-js-1.12

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The Office.context.document.url API seems to return the file location URL and the worksheet/workbook level custom properties are cleared when we close the excel document. We are looking for a method by which we can identify a document, like a unique identifier key which is same even when the document is shared